# Select values based on another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, sign

I have two dataframes of the same size, the same columns and same index.

df1:

```
symbol                      fund1  fund2  fund3  ...     ...    ...  
id   datetime                                                                  
10   2012-10-19 09:05:00     -100    0       0     50      0      0   
20   2012-10-19 09:10:00     0      300      0      0      0      0
```

df2:

```
symbol                      fund1  fund2  fund3  ...     ...    ...  
id   datetime                                                                  
10   2012-10-19 09:05:00   -0.5      0      0     0.005      0      0   
20   2012-10-19 09:10:00     0      -10     0      0      0      0
```

I would like to receive a new dataframe that takes the values from df1 only if the sign of each element in df1 is NOT the same (the opposite) than in df2.

So, the result for the example would be:

```
df_outcome:

symbol                         fund1   fund2     fund3  ...     ...    ...  
    id   datetime                                                                  
    10   2012-10-19 09:05:00     0       0       0      0      0      0   
    20   2012-10-19 09:10:00     0      300      0      0      0      0
```

I've found that there is a function: np.sign(df), I think I should first apply this function to both tables, but what should I do then to compare the values to these "sign" tables and, if they are opposite, element by element, take the values from df1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `where` with `np.sign` and inequality test:

```
df1.where(np.sign(df1) != np.sign(df2)).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
                        fund1  fund2  fund3  fund4  fund5  fund6
id datetime                                                     
10 2012-10-19 09:05:00    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
20 2012-10-19 09:10:00    0.0  300.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, great! Not expected that it's possible to do just in one line.

Comment: @Ekaterina Great!  I am glad I could help.  Would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) this solution?